# Error in applescript "Invalid index"

Tags: applescript, automator, error

I have an automator workflow which works fine except for a part of it - applescript.

This is how the workflow goes -

Run applescript (this part works fine) -

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Mail" to set theMessageText to content of (get first message of inbox)
    set x to text ((offset of "9" in theMessageText) + 2) thru ((offset of " " in theMessageText) - 1) of theMessageText
end run
```

Set value for variable (The name of the variable is 'number')

Get value for variable (I have made sure that this receives no direct input from previous actions. I am calling the variable 'number' here and I have duplicated this process 2 more times to call 2 more variables)

Run Applescript (This is the code I have problem with) -

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set cat to first item of input
    set x to second item of input
    set o to third item of input
    tell application "Contacts"
        set thePerson to make new person with properties {first name:"Testing", last name:"Auto"}
        make new phone at end of phones of thePerson with properties {label:"Main", value:x}
        repeat with z from 1 to o
            set a to item z of cat
            add thePerson to group a
        end repeat
        save
    end tell
end run
```

The error shown here is "Syntax Error - Can’t get item 2. Invalid index".

The point of the workflow is to get some contact details from an email and add them as a contact in address book (This isn't the full workflow as it is a fairly big one. I have shown only the relevant actions).

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you set before are not given via the `input`parameter. As long as you run your Automator Workflow as an **Automator Workflow** and not as an Application or Service, you can access your formerly set variables using the following:

```
tell application "Automator"
    set cat to value of variable "NameOfFirstVariable" of front workflow
    set x to value of variable "NameOfSecondVariable" of front workflow
    set o to value of variable "NameOfThirdVariable" of front workflow
end tell
```

inside your "Run Applescript" action.

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error "Can’t get item 2 of {3}". The problem seems to be in retrieving the second variable. The "Get value of Variable" action seems to be working fine. Every time I run the program, after the error dialog box, "item z" part of the code is highlighted. Any idea what is happening over here? Thanks for the help @ShooTerKo

Comment: You try `set a to item z of cat` inside `repeat with z from 1 to o`. It simply looks like `o` has a value greater than the amount of items in the list cat...